# From where does the fact that there are $10^{500}$ possible compactifications in string theory?

Tags: string-theory, quantum-gravity, string-theory-landscape

I have heard for quite a few times that there are $10^{500}$ possible compactifications in string theory. And in one of his lectures, physicist Leaonard Susskind explains that, this comes from the fact that, if you have a torus with 500 holes in it, in 10 dimensions, there are $10^{500}$ possibilities.

I don't really understand why he took a torus(10 dimensions is of course clear) and why is it 500 holed?

I suppose the 10-torus is  $  (S^{1})^{10}$. How this 10-torus and the Calabi-Yau manifolds are connected? And does it have indeed 500 holes in it?

can any one illuminate on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does the $10^{500}$ estimate for the number of stringy vacua come from?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2873/)

Answer (score 2):

This number - $10^{500}$ is not precise; it's an estimate. We simply don't know the exact number. Susskind's "explanation" is a hand-wavy way of explaining the estimate (note he doesn't explain why there are 500 holes).

[Source](https://www.mdpi.com/2218-1997/5/7/176/htm):

> One can roughly estimate the number of choices at each step, and argue that they combine to produce a combinatorially large number of metastable vacua. These arguments are still in their early days and there is as yet no consensus on the number; estimates range from $10^{500}$  which at the time it was made seemed large, to the recent $10^{272,000}$.

Here's the [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/JHEP12(2015)164) estimating the high end number.